# Domino app - how to access the source document in java during custom file attachment routine

Tags: java, upload, lotus-domino

This is a non-xpages application.

I have inherited some code that I need to tweak....this code is used in a drag&drop file attachment subform.   Normally, this will create a document in a separate dedicated .nsf that stores only attachments, and uses the main document's universalid as a reference to link the two....I need to change what the reference is to the value in a field already on the main document (where the subform is).

Java is challenging to me, but all I need to do is GET the value of the field from the main document (which has not necessarily been saved yet) and write that string value onto the attachment doc in that storage database, so I think I am just needing help with one line of code.

I will paste the relevant function here and hopefully someone can tell me how I get that value, or what else they need to see what is going on here.

You can see my commented-out attempt to write the field 'parentRef' in this code

...

```
private void storeUploadedFile( UploadedFile uploadedFile, Database dbTarget) {
    
    File correctedFile = null;
    RichTextItem rtFiles = null;
    Document doc = null;
    
    String ITEM_NAME_FILES = "file";
    
    try {
        
        if (uploadedFile==null) {
            return;
        }
        
        doc = dbTarget.createDocument();
        doc.replaceItemValue("form", "frmFileUpload");
        doc.replaceItemValue("uploadedBy", dbTarget.getParent().getEffectiveUserName() );
        Utils.setDate(doc, "uploadedAt", new Date() );
        doc.replaceItemValue("parentUnid", parentUnid);
        //doc.replaceItemValue("parentRef", ((Document) dbTarget.getParent()).getItemValue("attachmentDocKey"));
        
        
        //get uploaded file and attach it to the document
        fileName = uploadedFile.getClientFileName();
        
        File tempFile = uploadedFile.getServerFile();       //the uploaded file with a cryptic name
        fileSize = tempFile.length();
        targetUnid = doc.getUniversalID();
        
        correctedFile = new java.io.File( tempFile.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath() + java.io.File.separator + fileName );
        
        //rename the file on the OS so we can embed it with the correct (original) name
        boolean success = tempFile.renameTo(correctedFile);
        
        if (success) {
        
            //embed original file in target document
            rtFiles = doc.createRichTextItem(ITEM_NAME_FILES);
            rtFiles.embedObject(lotus.domino.EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", correctedFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
            
            success = doc.save();
            
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) { 

        e.printStackTrace();
        
    } finally {
        
        com.gadjj.Utils.recycle(rtFiles, doc);
        
        try {
            if (correctedFile != null) {
                //rename the temporary file back to its original name so it's automatically
                //removed from the os' file system.
                correctedFile.renameTo(uploadedFile.getServerFile());   
            }
        } catch(Exception ee) { ee.printStackTrace(); }
        
    }

}
```

}
...

Comment: So what is the problem?  Is this not working?  Where does the code break down?

Comment: It works fine as is, but I need to change it to write the value of a field from the form/doc you are filling out (random value generated in WebQueryOpen for a new doc).    This comments box does not let me get into the details of why, but I cannot figure out how to get the value of that field so I can write it at the time the attachment doc is written.  I am betting it is simple to do, but I just do not know the way to access the field to know what to write into the attachment doc.

Comment: In WebQueryOpen, you can get a handle on the document using the DocumentContext property.  You can then retrieve the parentRef value assuming that it is available on the document at this point.

Answer (score 0):

dbTarget.getParent does not do what you think it does. It returns a Session object that is the parent session containing all your objects. Casting it to (Document) won't give you your main document.

I don't see the declaration for it, but you appear to have a variable available called parentUNID. You can use it to get a handle on the main document.

You need to use the parentUNID value in a call to getDocumentByUNID() in order to retrieve the Document object representing your main document. But in order to do that, you need the Database object for the nsf file containing the main document, and if I understand you correctly, that is a different database than targetDb.

I'm going to have to assume that you already have that Database object in a variable called parentDb, or that you know the path to the NSF and can open it. In either case, your code would look like this (without error handling):

```
Document parentDoc = parentDb.getDocumentByUNID(parentUNID);
doc.replaceItemvalue("parentRef", parentDoc.getItemValue("attachmentDocKey"));
```

Comment: Richard,  thanks...I'm not there yet, but this helped.    I know I have the parentDoc now because I got a value off of it and wrote it to my attachments document.   But this new value, visible on  the page, is not coming over,   Remember the doc has not been SAVED with this new value, but is confusing is HCL documentation shows an example in isNewNote whereby they get a value and write it to a println statement if the doc is a new note (has not been saved, like mine),   Any ideas what I going on?  https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/11.0.1/basic/H_EXAMPLES_ISNEWNOTE_PROPERTY_JAVA.html

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean by something being "visible on the page", but "not coming over".  You said you read a value from parentDoc. Is that the attachmentDocKey value? Or some other value?  Also, I clearly see that you call doc.Save later in your code, so the fact that it had not been saved before should not be relevant as far as I can see. Once you've saved it, the parentRef item value that you replaced should be in the saved doc, and even before you called doc.Save it should be in the in-memory doc.

Comment: As for isNewNote, it is usually only relevant in cases where you need to know things like "does this document have a UNID yet?" (notes that have not been save yet do not), or "can the formulas on this form assume that all data has been filled in  and validated at least once before?"

Comment: I'm sorry I am not being clear. I have a main document with a button that calls this Java code, and it writes a small document to another database (thus other database holds nothing but small documents with the attachment). I need to pass a value feom the main document to this small 'attachment-storage' document to create a reference link between the main and the small document. The UNID is not good (I can explain why if necessary) so I want to pass a fieeld value instead. this value is a long random string that is inserted into a field on the main doc cia WebQueryOpen agent ...

Comment: ..and I have it visible on the main doc when I click the button, When the action is complete I should have a small doc in the 'attachments' database that contains this long string in a field named 'parentRef' but that value is not being written to parentRef field on the small one. The field is there but it is blank when I try now. The isNewNote sample code shows me that the value is available on the main document before it is actually saved, so I do not know why the value is blank on the 'attachment' doc.

Comment: sorry for all typos, I need to learn to proofread before posting because it does not let me edit a post that is not the most recent.

Comment: Re "The field is there but it is blank when I try now."  How are you determining that? Are you opening the document to look at it, or are you clicking on it in a view and bringing up the document properties box to look at the field properties? If it's a computed field on the "frmFileUpload" form, what is the computed value formula?

Comment: I am looking at the document properties of the 'attachment' document in the second database by way of seeing it in a view.  This little doc was created successfully, and the field I am wanting the value to go to is on the document, but the value is blank.   It is an editable text field that would be hidden to any users

Comment: Okay... Then it sounds like your call to getItemValue("attachmentDocKey") is returning an empty (or null) value. Is that the correct item name?  Have you used hasItem() to verify that it exists parentDoc? Have you tried getItemValueString() instead of getItemValue()? Have you split that line of code into a getItemValue() assigned to a temp variable and then a replaceItemValue from the temp variable, and stepped through it in the debugger to see what you're getting in th the temp?

Comment: I am now in the belief that this value is not going to be available BEFORE this main document is saved for the very first time, despite the isNewNote sample code that indicates that it would be.     If I try this with an existing document, the value is written onto the attachment doc fine , it is just not working whenever I try to access it from the main document before it is ever saved.    That sample code has put me on a wild goose chase.   I do appreciate your diligence and patience however.   Thank you for all of that.

Comment: Oh, it's the *main* document that is not saved yet???  In that case, you can't just open a new instance of it. You would have to pass the already-opened Document object into this code as an argument.

Comment: The main doc is parentDoc, and it is accessed by way of this code:  Document parentDoc = dbCurrent.getDocumentByUNID(parentUnid);    Maybe this is not the way to go about it, and instead like you said, pass it by way of an argument/object.   Remember, early on I said two things: 1.) I inherited this code and 2.) I struggle with Java.     So I am starting to get a grasp on what the person who wrote this was thinking.    All of this works perfectly if the main doc was previously saved and I am simply editing it.   It is when it is a new unsaved doc (isnewnote) where this does not work.

Comment: alright, that last comment has had me realize something.    This is attempting to get a handle on an existing doc (and has from the beginning)....it is WRITTEN to access already saved docs.     That is why this code is returning nothing into my attachKey variable because it never sets the parentDoc.   It makes sense now.   In Domino,  these calls to either:  System.out.println()  or printStackTrace....where do these show up in a broswer (I use Firefox normally)?    Tell me if you think I am off-base here.    I need to buy you lunch for your efforts.

Comment: In a browser app, Java agents redirect System.out the stream that is returned to the browser. For tracing/debugging, it's usually better to use the OpenLog code from OpenNTF. 

https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenLog

Comment: For a good introduction to Domino Java programming, there's a very old book written by the developer who did the work for Lotus. He's posted all the chapters as PDFs. Yes, it's out of date by more than 20 years, but most of the basic principles still apply and you can work out most of anything else you need from current documentation. The big omission is that it doesn't cover calling recycle(), because that wasn't a thing yet. But for web agents that do one thing and get out, it's not an issue.

http://bobzblog.com/tuxedoguy.nsf/dx/programming-domino-with-java-final-flush?opendocument

Comment: I am reading that old book thanks for the tip.   Would you happen to know if AgentContext (and subsequently DocumentContext) would be relevant in my code which is saved in a .java file and initiated by way of JavaScript (hence, it is really an 'agent'?)?  This code goes to great lengths to get a handle on the current document, which I named parentDoc, by way of looking in a view.  That is why I said I realized after reading more that it is WRITTEN to require a saved document.    I will repeat myself, I inherited this and was simply trying to tweak it, but it may require more than a quick tweak

Comment: maybe I found the answer to the last question early on in his book, where he states "As with applets and servlets, a Java class becomes an Agent by extending a specified
base class, in this case lotus.notes.AgentBase."

Comment: Is this code running in a browser? How does the JavaScript initiate running the Java? An agent is run either by asking the Domino HTTP task to run it by issuing an ?OpenAgent URL or an ?OpenDocument URL (for a WebQueryOpen event agent), or by triggering it in the Agent Manager through one of the available mechanisms (schedule, on creation/modification, on delivery of email, through mechanisms in formula or LotussScript code, or through a command issued on the server console. Anything else is not an agent. (Unless i'm forgetting something.)

Comment: It is running in a browser.   It seems to be an HTTP post that kicks this off, but it is hard to figure out how this is initiated, as the subform has several js scripts included and following the logic is difficult for me.   I am going to keep picking at it, and might be able to get this to work, I don't know.   But I really do appreciate all of your time and effort in trying to help me